# Issues with Find Formula

Tags: formula, find

We have a string coming from another system, and I want to find a specific part of it in Salesforce, but the FIND formula is not working for me.

This is the string I'm doing a search in:

```
[{“title”:“Company Name”,“value”:“Hation”},{“title”:“Number of Providers in Organization”,“value”:“101+“}]
```

And this is my formula:

```
FIND( Zoom_Custom_Questions__c , "Number of Providers in Organization" )
```

**I'm getting just 0 for every record.**

Any idea what's happening here?

Thank you

Comment: what result you want.  if  "Number of Providers in Organization"  text is present or not.   or value  of this i.e.  "101+"

Comment: I want to get the index on when the string starts.
Also, I'm not using APEX, just the FIND function in the custom formula fields in Salesfore

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments to FIND are reversed

From the doc: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5

> FIND(search_text, text[,
> start_num]) and replace
> search_text with the string you want to find, replace
> text with the field or expression you want to search, and
> replace start_num with the number of the character from which
> to start searching from left to right.